# Calendar not popping up in Instrumented Android App in Test Workbench

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

**Tool:** IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench 6.3.0
**OS:** Windows 7

**Problem:**
In MobileFirst app have a date field. When clicked, a calendar pops up and the user can select the day, month and year.

Instrumented the above app in Test Workbench so that Record and Playback can be done. When Date field is clicked in the instrumented app (while doing Record) calendar does not pop up. Keypad pops up.

**Find below code written for the Date field.**

`<input class="fin-input  fin-input-date ng-pristine" type="date" ng-model="creditCard.selectedFromDate" ng-change="creditCard.selectFromDate()"/>`

Comment: Only JQuery Mobile & Dojo Mobile are supported. Is your calendar  view coming from one of there 2 SDK ?

Comment: The code for calender is written in HTML, the view comes from web browser. It is not coming from the above SDK's.

Comment: can you share your app with me ? (if Android). I yes, send it my email please

Comment: yeah sure. Can you share your Email please ?

Comment: @RakeshManusani, you do not require dom's email address - just upload it to Google Drive or Dropbox. We shouldn't give you our emails addresses.

Comment: @dom, you can download it here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_oG-jJKHvh4dEozVWo5bFVnSDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RakeshManusani I got it . working on it this morning

Comment: @RakeshManusani what is your Android version ?

Comment: @RakeshManusani I run your app on an emulator with Android 4.4.2 and I don't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RakeshManusani  can you also update RTW with the last release please ?

Comment: @dom Will update to latest release and try

Comment: @dom Have updated both IBM Mobile first Studio and Test Workbench to latest Versions. i.e.to   IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0 and IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7.0. Created the app using latest Version of Mobilefirst Studio and instrumented the app using latest version of Test Workbench, but still the abov problem persists.                          Running the app on Device: Nexus4__Android Version:5.1

Comment: @RakeshManusani Can you open a ticket in IBM Rational support please (http://www.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/support?lnk=msdTS-supo-uken) describe our conversation ? I will intercept the PMR and we will be able to make a remote session if required

Comment: @RakeshManusani, please update the question with an answer once the PMR is resolved. Also mention the PMR number.

Comment: @dom: Apologies for the delay.   For raising a ticket with IBM rational support I require a customer ID. Currently I am using the trial version of IBM Mobilefirst Platform Test Workbench 8.7.0, so it's not possible to raise a ticket. Any suggestions on how to go forward with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a product defect. In order to resolve it you will need to open a PMR (support ticket).

As an IBM customer you will be able to do so by following these instructions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639